# MUI TextField Animation not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have a TextField component where I have placeholder and value and When I have icon inserted from InputProps prop the Icon shows and the animation that I have on TextField which changes from placeholder to value doesn't show up but if I don't have InputProps the animation is showing as expected. What can be the problem ?

I am expexting to see the animation even tho I have the icon in the textfield

```
<TextField
          {...params}
          error={touched && invalid}
          helperText={touched && error}
          label={label}
          margin={margin}
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            ...inputProps,
            readOnly: isReadOnlyTextField,
          }}
          placeholder={isShowPlaceholder ? placeholder : ''}
          variant={`${isOutlined ? 'outlined' : 'standard'}`}
          InputLabelProps={InputLabelProps}
          className={className}
        />
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide the usage scenarios of this `TextField` and the `inputProps` you use? Otherwise it's hard to reproduce the problem.